# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, flutter

Members
Kindly help me out on this one !
I've tried every trick in the book to make my flutter project work on android studio.But still stuck with the same subject issue. Details from VS code below

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > File 'C:\Users\saud.khan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' specified for property 'androidJar' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 6):

I have got the same issue, Below is my update,
Please check the response of `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G2208, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/anoobbava/flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (3 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/anoobbava/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/anoobbava/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

As per flutter doctor, it seems to be mine is working with the `Android SDK version 29.0.2`

So update the `android/app/build.gradle` with `compileSdkVersion 28`  to `compileSdkVersion 29`

If your version existing is 27 then change to above and try.  I hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error, in the end, I solved it in the following way:

Go to the `SDK\platforms\android-29` and copy the android.jar file and put it in the android-28 folder

Comment: Well done, we were blocked since 2 weeks. Our android-31 folder was little empty but got a sub folder named android-12. We go inside and copy paste all for android-31.

Answer (score 4):

This error may occur because the specified version of the Android SDK in `[YOUR_PROJECT]/android/app/src/build.gradle` does not match with your installed Android SDK version on your computer (if it exists).

## 1 - Check the version and the location of your Android SDK :

```sh
$ flutter doctor -v

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.2)
    • Android SDK at [PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK]/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.2
```

## 2 - Verify your Android SDK version in`build.gradle`

- Go to `[YOUR_PROJECT]/android/app/build.gradle`
- Verify if the Android SDK version in`build.gradle` is the same than specified in the `flutter doctor` command above.

```
android {
  ...
  compileSdkVersion 28
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 28
    ...
  }
}
```

- If not, adapt the Android SDK `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` according your Computer Installation

Answer (score 0):

I had a fairly old phone running on Android 6.0, I just went to the SDK folder.
We can find it in the Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms if you have two android folders just copy and paste android.jar from one to another folder(Generally with one number less) and then run the flutter code again, the app should go to phone's debug mode and then open the app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because you previously installed android studio. So in order to remove error first u have to go c/user/xyz/appData/local/Android/Sdk/platforms and one with less no like in my case android 31.i copy android folder from android 32 and paste in android31 so its solve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but, if you ever face this again:

1. Identify which version you are having problem with (in this case 28)
2. Open SDK manager: Tools > SDK manager
3. In the platform tools tab, uncheck the problematic version
4. Apply
5. Mark the version again (this will re-download it)

Open the `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platforms` folder and check if you now find the jar under the version you just downloaded.

Hit `make`

Answer (score 0):

In one of the emulators I was missing the androidJar file, so make sure it exists where it gives you the path to find it.
Secondly, the path on my C drive showed that the 'sdk' file was actually spelled 'Sdk'.  Once I fixed the path on my C drive with 'sdk' everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

File 'C:\Users\saud.khan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' specified for property 'androidJar' does not exist.

the problem is mentioned here .jar file is missing either copy the android.jar file from any other installed sdk or delete the sdk and reinstall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).